# globals and includes in PHP

Tags: php, include, global, require, bootstrapping

I have a bootstrap script.

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
  $bootstrapFoo = 'foo';
```

and a main script.

**main.php**

```
<?php
  require_once 'bootstrap.php';
  print $bootstrapFoo; // this is working

  // I include a subscript
  include_once 'subscript.php';
```

**subscript.php**

```
<?php
  print $bootstrapFoo; // this is NOT working.
```

my solution :

```
<?php
  global $bootstrapFoo;
  print $bootstrapFoo; // now that's working
```

> Is this the right way ?

*ps: no duplicates found.*

Comment: That code, as given, should work just fine. You're probably mixing in a `function` somewhere.

Comment: @deceze please can you remove the duplicate thing ? your post doesn't really give a decent solution. i am not using any function if you catch the code I wrote. Hence neither can I use 'use' instruction, nor passing a variable in an included file like a function's argument. the only way i see in my case is the global keyword which you do not recommend, then 'is this the right way?' question I asked seems to be answered but what about in the files' scope scenario and which alternatives are out there ?
please remove the duplicate thing, it didn't help me out. thanks

Comment: As I said, it is extremely strange that your code *doesn't* work as is. Is this literally the exact code you're using?

Comment: @deceze I was in fact using a function somewhere, I guess that's a sign of a code turning spaghetti, thanks.